# How to center UIImage and UILabel horizontally together?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an image for user's icon and a label for user's name
And I want the image and the label align center horizontally in the screen.

Because the length of the label changes as the length of user's name, (the size of image is fixed)
I can't set the positon as a fixed value.

Now I change the positon of the image and lalel at runtime,
It's not convenient.

Is there any good way to do this?

Thank you:)

Here is the snapshot:

[image]
[image]
[image]

All right.
I know there is no a very convenient way to do this just with IB.
And I learn the function of [label sizetoFit].
It's very helpful.

In android, it's very convenient to do this just with the xml layout.
But in ios I have to write code to control the positon of image and label.
Yes...Not too bad.

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: Can you pls post some snapshots?

Comment: I have add a snapshot. The size of the image is fixed, but the positon should be changed with the length of the label.

Sorry for my poor English..

Answer (score 3):

```
[label sizetoFit];
label.center =imageView.center;
```

this will make the label center on the image center..and it will appear on top...

now you can just use `CGRect` manipulation to move the label origin downwards based on your image height.

Edit .. now you can do this ..

```
CGRect frame = label.frame;
frame.origin.x -= imageview.frame.size.width/2 - 15; // you can change 15 to a  more appropriate number based on your preference..
label.frame = frame;
```

Do the above after you do the 2 lines of code given on top in my answer.

Comment: [label sizetoFit] works well.
But label.center = imageView.center; doesn't;
Maybe I didn't express clearly.
The image and label have the same positon.y, but the position.x is different.
The image is on the left of the label and the label is on the right of the image.

Comment: explain with screenshots what you want.. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MARGIN 10.0f
```

In your -layoutSubviews method, do this:

```
[ label sizeToFit ] ;
CGRect r = label.frame ;
r.origin = (CGPoint){ CGRectGetMaxX( imageView.frame ) + MARGIN, CGRectGetMidY( imageView.frame ) - 0.5 * r.size.height } ;
label.frame = CGRectIntegral( r ) ;
```

**update here's how to center the the image view and label unit**

`bounds` should be set to bounds of enclosing view

```
//
// center an image view + label in parent view, with label to right of image view
//

[ label sizeToFit ] ;
CGSize size = (CGSize){ imageView.image.size.width + MARGIN + label.bounds.size.width,
    MAX( imageView.image.size.height, label.bounds.size.height } ;
CGRect r = (CGRect){ 
    { CGRectGetMidX( bounds ) - 0.5 * size.width, 
        CGRectGetMidY( bounds ) - 0.5 * size.height }, 
    size }
} ;

CGRect imageFrame, labelFrame ;
CGRectDivide( r, &imageFrame, &labelFrame, imageView.image.size.width, CGRectMinXEdge ) ;
imageView.frame = imageFrame ;
labelView.frame = labelFrame ;
```

Comment: where `MARGIN` is how much space you want between the right edge of your image view and the left edge of your label

Comment: I should point out that text in a `UILabel` is centered vertically, so you could also just set the height of your label to be the same as the height of your image view to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yes, the height shoult be the same. Thank you. And I add two more snapshots.

Comment: I think the positon of the image should be changed with the length of the label.

Comment: You mean you want to center the whole thing? If so you have to measure the entire space required and then work from that

Answer (score 1):

Do some calculation

Width of UIImageView + Offset width (Space b/n UIImageView and UILabel "Keep this as constant value") + UILabel Width = You Will get some 'X' width.

iPhone screen width is 460.

320-X = Remaining width.

Remaining width/2 pass this value to UIImageView's X value. This might help you.

Comment: Yes, I did by this way. But I'm sorry. Maybe the width is 320 :)